# How to 'move' grub or MBR to another partition on dual boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, mbr

First of all, I am quite new on this so I may say things that are very wrong, so I apologize in advance.

The problem that I have is that I have Windows and Ubuntu on dual boot, having Windows in an internal drive and Ubuntu in an external one (which I connect through an USB-C port), and when I turn on my PC without having the Ubuntu drive connected, my computer shows GRUB rescue. I think this may be caused because it stored the necessary boot files into the SSD, so my question is whether it would be better (or possible) to move the GRUB bootloader into the external drive or somehow move the GRUB files into the Windows drive.

The problem only appears when my external drive was disconnecting and once when restarting  the pc from Ubuntu. Windows works without problems when I choose its bootloader from the boot options from BIOS and when it is ran from GRUB (with the other drive still connected).

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? You want Windows boot loader on internal drive & grub on external. And UEFI/BIOS to boot external first & then boot internal drive. Typically you just need to reinstall boot loaders, but if UEFI, you need an ESP - efi system partition on external drive for grub to correctly install. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tink I understood correctly. Regarding to UEFI/BIOS I'm not sure, is there a way to check it? I think I may be using BIOS but I'm really not sure.
I have now the Boot-info file from Boot repair. I have not selected the option to upload it directly (I'm not sure if that was what I had to do). I have uploaded it manually to Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/rdZ58Q8H). Is there anything else I had to do?

Comment: Your system is UEFI, you have both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode, but a BIOS version of grub in MBR of sdb. And sdb is MBR(msdos) partitioned. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI, but Ubuntu does not (it should). You can either convert sdb to BIOS boot by reinstalling grub in BIOS mode, or add an ESP FAT32 partition to sdb, update fstab with new ESP's UUID & reinstall UEFI version of grub to sdb. If you have sdb in BIOS boot mode, it will not offer dual boot  of Windows as UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Once you start booting from UEFI menu, you cannot switch.

Comment: So, please correct me if I'm wrong, what I'm trying to do is being able to boot using grub when the external drive is connected having access to both OS and using windows boot manager if it isn't to directly boot to windows. To achieve this, would the first option be viable?

Comment: (And just to make sure I understood the process to follow) It would consist on reinstalling grub in BIOS mode into sdb? Or is there any other thing to do?

Comment: In BIOS mode, you cannot dual boot from grub menu, only UEFI boot menu. Not sure how UEFI boot menu handles one install in UEFI and one in BIOS. Some old ones required you to go into UEFI and change boot mode from UEFI to CSM/Legacy/BIOS mode. Newer ones seem to recognize mode and correctly boot install. Best case would be to convert external to gpt, add an ESP & use UEFI boot for Ubuntu. But if Always booting from UEFI menu, you can use BIOS boot for Ubuntu. How you boot Ubuntu live installer, UEFI or BIOS is then how it repairs or installs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help, I'll take a look into how to do it all.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Boot-Repair can reinstall grub using its advanced mode. You choose an install and then drive where to install grub. If UEFI, you must have the ESP. If you want BIOS, you must boot live installer in BIOS mode as then it will install BIOS version of grub. You may be able to use gdisk to convert drive from MBR to gpt, but then have to totally reinstall grub. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: I attempted to do what you said, but I've ended with the same behavior as before.
I generated 2 bootinfos from boot repair, one after using boot-repair and the other after using mbr2gpt.

[Bootinfo after boot-repair](https://pastebin.com/3QNpuDvQ)
[Bootinfo after mbr2gpt](https://pastebin.com/f55gz1jn)

Comment: Your sdb  is still MBR, and does not have an ESP on sdb. You do have Ubuntu UEFI boot files in ESP on NVMe drive. If you ran gdisk to convert sdb drive, you have to save it after conversion. Then add a new ESP partition somewhere on drive with gparted after shrinking some partition. Then using Boot-Repair in Advanced mode, choose install in sdb & sdb drive for install. If that boots without issue, then change boot order in UEFI. Conversion to gpt will break boot as all new UUIDs, but reinstall of grub should fix that.

Comment: I now tried ding that, first running gdisk to create GPT and checking that I had it done correctly (I followed [this guide](https://www.explorelinux.com/convert-disk-mbr-to-gpt-on-linux/) to be sure), which removed my partitions after failing to recover them from the backup I had (not a big deal rn). After diong that, I created the EFI partition (100MB, FAT32) and reinstalled ubuntu with an UEFI live installer and selected the EFI partition as EFI and another partition as the main fs. However, it works just as before [bootinfo after all I did](https://pastebin.com/UMspRina).

Comment: I am now reinstalling the OS (I had backups of some important files, the rest can be restored easily). I took extra attention about the partitions. I have set them up [like this](https://imgur.com/a/YqDTBRH). I hope they are right and I will be able to boot correctly

Comment: There is a bug in Ubiquity installer, it only installs to first drives ESP, no matter what you say. There are several work arounds in bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079

Comment: I finally got it to work. I reinstalled it again and forcefully set the efi partition. It reused the boot files from my NVMe but with boot-repair I got it to work as I wanted. I now have 2 entries in my BIOS boot devices (started as UEFI) but I can live with it. [Partition creation images](https://imgur.com/a/YqDTBRH), [Bootinfo from repair](https://pastebin.com/8716jP7c).

There is something else I would need. Is there a way to remove the old boot entry of Ubuntu from my NVMe with windows? It's still there and i won't use it anymore. [Boot menu image](https://imgur.com/a/bLbmNWd)

Comment: The boot menu entries now only show up as uefi and when the drive is connected, Windows boot manager still works and both entries from the external drive boot ubuntu (Is having 2 entries normal?)

Comment: You need to know which entry is which. And most UEFI remove UEFI entries or change them, if a drive is disconnected. But all external drives boot from the USB drive using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.  To see UEFI entries: `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see GUID/partUUID that UEFI uses for ESP: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` If you can then boot external you can remove UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr. See: `man efibootmgr`  and:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

Comment: I removed Boot0000 and set as inactive Boot0001 (because I'm not confident about removing it), producing [these changes](https://pastebin.com/REfj6Eh0). I now rebooted my PC and everything is fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the only issue may be if you disconnect external drive, the ubuntu entry may change to some sort of default & not work. But you should be able to boot an entry  from UEFI boot menu for the external drive. That entry would be similar to the entries you used to boot live installer to originally install Ubuntu.

Comment: Unplugging it and plugging it back it messed the order but everything is working fine